# My train has been delayed

Tags: present-perfect

To my friend at night, is it correct to say:

"Sorry, I am late because my train has been delayed"

Indeed, this is still relevant to the present because I am late currently.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct (at any time of day!) if you are phoning your friend while you are still on the journey.

If you are apologising for having arrived late, you would say "My train was delayed".

Answer (score 0):

If you are already at your friends house (but late) then you say your train "was delayed".

If you are calling your friend from the station to say you will be late because your train has not left on schedule then your train "has been delayed".

Comment: We only use the present perfect when this action is right now, when this is past (even if this is a little relevant) I have to use the past?

Comment: @Meedfried I can't answer your grammatical question. All I have done is write what sounds right to a native speaker.

Comment: (In British English) you would use the present perfect while waiting for, or travelling on, a train that is currently running late. Once you leave the train, the delay passes into the past!

Answer (score 0):

I think the moment you get on the train is when the grammar changes.

So, if you call your friend from the station while you're waiting for the train, you  could say, "Sorry, I'm going to be late because my train's been delayed."

If you're already on the train when you call your friend, you'd say, "Sorry, I'm going to be late because my train was delayed."

This is my instinct as an American speaker; I think the Brits generally let the present perfect linger for a bit longer than we do.